# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when setting selected index of listbox in KeyDown event

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote C# code to view records in a list box.

I've attached a KeyDown event to a text box as follows:

```
    private void txtitem_code_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            listBox1.Focus();
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

But if I press the down arrow key, it gives me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for
>   'SelectedIndex'.

Please help me to debug this problem.

Comment: The error means your listbox doesn't have any items in it yet, so there's nothing to select. Therefore you can't set the selected index as 0, because that index doesn't exist.

Comment: Please give me some Solution to it !

Comment: @Pramu Add at least one item to your listbox

Comment: Its already have Two Items

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on the line and debugging to verify how many items are in `listBox1`?

Comment: @Pramu _"Its already have Two Items"_ ...that can't be true. If it did have those items, you wouldn't have the error. The computer doesn't lie to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This is the line which is causing the exception to be thrown. `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` sort of gives away what is wrong, you are trying to select the 0th element however it does not exist as the list box is empty.

Either add some items to `listBox1` or do a check to see if `listBox1` is empty before trying to change the selected item, like:

```
private void txtitem_code_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        listBox1.Focus();
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the issue, but it seems to me that the error is coming from the selected index check. Of course this may be based on some assumptions I am making.

Note what microsoft says:

**ListBox.SelectedIndex Property**
Gets or sets the zero-based index of the currently selected item in a ListBox.

**Property Value - Int32** A zero-based index of the **currently selected item.** A value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected.

**ArgumentOutOfRangeException**
The assigned value is less than -1 or greater than or equal to the item count.

**ArgumentException**
The SelectionMode property is set to None.

**SelectionMode**
Either the One or None value of SelectionMode.

**ArgumentException**
An attempt was made to assign a value that is not a SelectionMode value of One or None.

**InvalidEnumArgumentException**
An attempt was made to assign the MultiExtended value of SelectionMode to the control.

Based on this information, I would verify that the listbox does have data and that the selectmode is set to 1.

This is just a starting point. Have you checked the number of items in the listbox(listBox1.Items.Count)? And have you checked the number of **selected** items in the listbox(listbox1.GetSelectedIndices().Count())?

Comment: lol, while I was looking up MS properties for list box, Tom Dee was answering. Oh well, I'll keep trying =)